# $ \int_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}|f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2)f_3(x_1+x_2)|dx_1dx_2 \leq \prod_{j=1}^3 ||f_j||_{3/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_1,f_2,f_3\in L^{3/2} (\mathbb{R},m)$. Prove that  $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}|f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2)f_3(x_1+x_2)|dx_1dx_2 \leq  \prod_{j=1}^3 ||f_j||_{3/2}.$$

I'm thinking of applying Holder's inequality for $L^p$ space $\int |fg|d\mu \leq ||f||_p||g||_q$, but I can't find the way to do it. Can anyone suggest some hints, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\iint |f_1(x_1)|^{3/2} |f_3(x_1+x_2)|^{3/2} dx_1 dx_2 = 
\int |f_1|^{3/2} \cdot \int |f_3|^{3/2},
$$
and a similar equality holds for $\iint |f_2(x_2)|^{3/2} |f_3(x_1+x_2)|^{3/2} dx_1 dx_2$.

Then, using the generalized Holder inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
& \iint |f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2) f_3(x_1+x_2)| dx_1 dx_2 
\\ & = \iint |f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2)|^{1/2}|f_1(x_1) f_3(x_1+x_2)|^{1/2} |f_2(x_1) f_3(x_1+x_2)|^{1/2} dx_1 dx_2 
\\ & \leq
\left(\iint|f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2)|^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}
\left(\iint|f_1(x_1) f_3(x_1+x_2)|^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}
\left(\iint|f_2(x_2) f_3(x_1+x_2)|^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}
\\ & =
\left(\int|f_1|^{3/2} \int |f_2|^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}
\left(\int|f_1|^{3/2} \int |f_3|^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}
\left(\int|f_2|^{3/2} \int |f_3|^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}
\end{align}
$$
and the required inequality follows.